# Migration and Realm database version

Tags: android, realm, database-migration

I have a question about migrations in the Kingdom. In an application that catches the database version 0, after an update has been made, everything happens fine, however, when a clean installation of the application is done, it presents problems when it reopens because it tries to perform the migration to 1. What would be the correct way to proceed with these cases? How can I set the version?

Comment: Does a clean installation imply that all the files are removed? Since the version is stored inside the Realm, it is like starting all over.

Comment: Exactly, an installation on a new device. The problem would be to pass the migration schema version 1. When doing the update of the old app to the new one it works normal, but if the installation is done in a new device, to kill and to open the application again entails in exceptions for trying to realize the migration again.

Comment: When an app get the first instance, the Realm file is created. The schema version is undefined, so the model classes are used and the schema version is set to what you specify in the `RealmConfiguration` (1 in your case). Next time the app starts, the version on disk and in the configuration is the same, and no migration is executed. Do you set the schema version in your configuration?

Comment: Yes, I am inserting version 1, but I think I'm forgetting some other detail or doing something else wrong, because a test project worked.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `RealmConfiguration`, your migration and how to get an instance?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The problem was not in the migration of Realm, it was in a return of a control made for an update of the application that did not call the correct method in a new installation.

Answer (score 0):

On the migration class you need to verify the `oldVersion` before, then proceed with the migration only when it's really necessary.

```
// Example migration adding a new class
RealmMigration migration = new RealmMigration() {
  @Override
  public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

     // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
     RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

     // Migrate to version 1
     if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.create("Person")
            .addField("name", String.class)
            .addField("age", int.class);
        oldVersion++;
     }

     // Migrate to version 2: Add a primary key + object references
     // Example:
     if (oldVersion == 1) {
        schema.get("Person")
            .addField("id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
            .addRealmObjectField("favoriteDog", schema.get("Dog"))
            .addRealmListField("dogs", schema.get("Dog"));
        oldVersion++;
     }
  }
}
```

[Realm Migration example](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations)